# SUPEE 5344 patch seems to download Enterprise Edition patch

Tags: security, patches, supee-5344

When trying to download the patch SUPEE 5344 for CE 1.7.x from https://www.magentocommerce.com/download the patch has a header which seems to say it's a patch for EE 1.12.

> SUPEE-5345 | EE_1.12.0.2 | v1 | 2d36f61cf684ed26286b6d10307fcb99dd47ff02 | Thu Feb 5 19:39:01 2015 +0200 | v1.12.0.2..HEAD

Is this is a mistake on the behalf of Magento, and where can I find the patch for CE?

Update: To make clear, this is not a problem with the filename of the patch, I'm aware SUPEE-5344 changes to 5345 when downloading for CE 1.7.x, the problem comes when you open the file and see the file is intended for Magento EE 1.12

Comment: Interesting, i just downloaded the SUPEE-5344 patch for 1.7. (select SUPEE-5344 - Magento-CE-v1.7.x (0.01 MB)) from the list and the file name is PATCH_SUPEE-5345_CE_1.7.0.2_v1-2015-02-10-08-11-22.sh

Comment: Actually the filenames should be named according to their version (either CE or EE)

Comment: Sorry, I should have made clear, the filename is indeed correct (PATCH_SUPEE-5345_CE_1.7.0.2_v1-2015-02-10-08-11-22.sh), the patch SUPEE-5344 changes the last number depending on which version you download it for. This is a known 'issue' and hasn't caused problems in the past. If you open the file you'll see the header reads 'EE_1.12.0.02' which implies the file is for the Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the lines after this header are

```
__PATCHFILE_FOLLOWS__
diff --git app/code/core/Enterprise/Logging/Block/Adminhtml/Grid/Filter/Ip.php app/code/core/Enterprise/Logging/Block/Adminhtml/Grid/Filter/Ip.php
```

Then you actually have the patch for EE 1.12.

If not, Magento just copied the EE patch file, removed the enterprise specific changes and forgot to update the header.

Comment: This would be a very interesting issue especially since this was the shoplift patch, no?

Comment: I have checked and you're right, there are no changes to the Enterprise folder in the patch. This solves it, I have the CE patch but Magento simply forgot to update the header.